# Block the stepper form if the user does not press a button

Tags: javascript

I am executing the realization of a step form (stepper), I found the code on an example of w3c (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps).

How this form works is for me and that's okay.

Having no experience in javascript, however, I would need to implement a small part, which I have difficulty making.

From the code you can see that in the javascript function: validateForm ()

until the user fills in the input field, if he tries to press the next button, the user will not be able to continue until it is filled in.

What I would need is to delete the input field that I do not need and replace it with a button, so that the user is forced to press it.

There will therefore be 3 buttons:

- Previous
- Button I need
- Next

Until the user presses on (the button I need), pressing the next button will be unable to move forward.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you say us wich input field do you want to remove? There a lot of input fields in your linked example.

Comment: @Reporter all, I just want to add one more button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the button you need, which will `doStuff()`, meaning will set the flag to `true` so user can advance to the next tab:

```
<div style="float:right;">
   <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
   <button type="button" id="doStuffBtn" onclick="doStuff()">Click</button>
   <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
</div>
```

Set a flag to `false` and check the flag value before moving to the next tab:

```
var nextAvailable = false;

function doStuff(n) {
    nextAvailable = true;
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  if (nextAvailable || n < 0) {    
    nextAvailable = false;
  
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
      // ... the form gets submitted:
      document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
      return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
  }
}
```

Full working example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTS2JKJT1W8K).

Comment: your example is just what I was looking for and for this I am grateful! The only problem is that when for example the user goes to the second step, if he wants to go back to the previous one he is obliged to press the click button.

Technically once the block is passed (click button) it should go back without constraints

Comment: Just replace the `if` statement with `if (nextAvailable || n < 0)`. Updated my answer and the linked example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution and for your time. I wish you a good day.